# iPhone can't access internet/iMessage

Tags: iphone, internet

My wife's iPhone 5 is exhibiting strange behavior:

- It isn't receiving iMessages.
- It can't access the internet.
- It can *send* texts, but they come across as plain SMS instead of iMessage.

I'm sitting next to her with an identical phone on the same plan, and mine is working perfectly.

What's causing this?  (Or, what should I google to find more information?  My searches so far have proven fruitless.)

Comment: Is airplane mode on? How about cellular data? Is the phone able to send iMessages or access the internet on WiFi?

Comment: Airplane mode is off, cellular data is on.

Comment: Try cycling cellular data (turn it off, then back on). Again, does it connect on WiFi? Try rebooting the phone completely (hold both buttons until the Apple logo appears).

Comment: Over wi-fi it works fine: can access internet, can send/receive iMessages.

Comment: Cycling cellular data didn't help, rebooting the phone worked.  Post that as an answer and I'll upvote & accept.  Would love to know what causes this problem.

Comment: Are the APN settings correct? Which country/carrier?

Comment: @IlariScheinin, for my particular case, the APN settings were correct (I assume, as they didn't need to be changed once the phone was rebooted), the country was the US, and the carrier was AT&T.  The solution below did turn out to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rebooting the phone by holding both buttons simultaneously until the Apple logo appears.

Restarting iOS will fix a lot of problems (as does restarting any computer) and should usually be tried as a first resort.

Comment: For some reason I'm still not thinking of my phone as a computer; obvious solutions like this are escaping me.

Comment: I'm not sure what caused your specific issues but a lot of these kinds of problems can be fixed by rebooting the phone. I've seen similar issues with iMessage not working (only green SMS) and rebooting fixed the issue. Not sure what causes them, but it is a computer just like any other - rebooting is a quick fix that restarts all of the system services (including what manages cellular data).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Setting > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings